# How to approach an Object Oriented API with JSON-RPC?

Tags: json-rpc

I have an API in C# that won't map to JSON-RPC due to the fact that JSON-RPC is Procedurally oriented.
How in JSON-RPC would you represent an Object Oriented API?
I can of course use the JSON-RPC extensions so that the request would look like:

```
{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", method:"ObjectName.Method", "params":[], "id": 1 }
```

But it feels kinda hackish and also requires a lot of work to define.
I can also include it as a parameter but again it just doesn't feel right.
Is there a best practice regarding working against an Object Oriented API using JSON-RPC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON-RPC is JSON Remote *Procedure* Call and by default procedure oriented.

However if you work over HTTP you can see each RPC service as object. I.e. if you access `/foo/bar` and call `beep` over JSON-RPC over HTTP then you call `beep` method of `foo` service of `bar` object.

Otherwise you may do it the way all OOP mapped over procedure calls:

```
foo.bar(x1,x2) -> bar(foo,x1,x2)
```

Where foo is "pointer" to object, for RPC it may be object UUID. (That is how it is actually done in some RPCS).

So you call

```
f=new integer(0);
f.add(10);
f.add(20);
x=f.get();
delete f;
```

Goes to:

```
client:   new("integer",0)
server:   return "23ab3cb45"
client:   add("23ab3cb45",10);
client:   add("23ab3cb45",20);
client:   get("23ab3cb45");
server:   return 30
client:   delete("23ab3cb45");
```

Comment: So an extension method is not a good idea and I should pass it as a parameter?

Comment: @the_drow No because (a) you limit yourself to specific object so basically you can't allocate objects dynamically (b) AFAIK using object IDs is common practice in RPC. (c) Using "." in methods name is generally not so good idea (IMHO)

Comment: @Artyom curious if "generally" using '.' is not a good idea. For example for a different problem, I find "questions.new", "questions.unanswered" readable and acceptable. Is your comment specific to a language/implementation/use case in question?